# How to refresh a layer in leaflet.js without flickering

Tags: leaflet, layers

We have an application with multiple layers, one of which is has to dynamically change based on new tiles from the server.
The base layer doesn't change, the overlay layer uses transparent png tiles, which are regularly updated.
The overlay layer has some code to make sure the tiles are not cached, without this the image doesn't change:

```
var dynLayer = L.tileLayer('base/dyn/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{test}', {
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    tms: true,
    noWrap:true,
    test: function() { 
        return Math.random(); 
    }
});
```

To refresh the changes the layer redraw method is called on a timer:

```
dynLayer.redraw();
```

Calling reload does not reload the images from the server.

This is based on an existing Windows application that's graphics heavy and has been modified to create tiles instead of drawing on the screen,

Using a vector layer isn't an option because it would require rewriting the server code.

The issue is that the overlay flickers when it is redrawn. Is there some plugin or other way of redrawing the layer without causing a flicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redrawing that special Tile Layer, why not using a 2nd (or even more) Tile Layer on top of the previous, so that you keep the previous tiles visible?

Then you can hide the previous one after some time, or when all viewport tiles of the new layer are loaded.

I think I had a demo of such thing, but I could not find it.

Comment: I have tried this, removing the old layer on the 'load' event. Although it helps there is still some flickering. I was hoping there would be some built-in solution